# maximal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

$\mathcal{H}$ stands for an  Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, with inner product $\langle{\cdot}| {\cdot}\rangle$ and the norm $\|{\cdot}\|$ and let $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$.
I look for an example of maximal vector $x\in \mathcal{H}$ for  $T\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ i.e. a vector $x$ satisfying $\|x\|=1$ and $\|Tx\|=\|T\|$.

Comment: Can you find such a vector on a finite-dimensional space? Then you can do it on a finite-dimensional subspace of $\mathcal H$.

Comment: What about $0$ operator?

Comment: we assume that $T$ is non zero operator

Comment: unfortunately I don't find such a vector on a finite-dimensional space.

Comment: @Phdstudent do you want an example of such operator and a hilbert space?

Comment: Yes even in finite dimensional hilbert space.

Comment: A non-trivial question is of an operator, where such vector does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the  shift operator $S:l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ such that $S(x_1,x_2....)=(0,x_1,x_2...).$

Then $||S||_2=1$ and $||Se_1||_2=1$ a where $e_1=(1,0..0...)$ and $||e_1||_2=1$

Also you can take shift the operator $T:l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ such that $T(x_1,x_2...)=(x_2,x_3....)$ and the vector $e_2=(0,1,0..0..)$

Now in the finite dimensional case take the hilbert space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual inner product and the bounded linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(a,b)=(a,0)$

You can easily prove that $||T||_2=1$ and $||Te_1||_2=1$ where $e_1=(1,0)$ and $||e_1||_2=1$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This is example where $H$ is infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.  Could you please give me an example where $H$ is finite-dimensional Hilbert space?? Thank you very much

Comment: ok i will edit my answer providing also such an example

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

consider the simple example where $T$ is the identity operator.

Then every vector that satisfies $\| x\|=1$ is a maximal vector, because the operator norm of the identity operator is $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your  answer but I want an example  when T is  not equal to identity